# Low Impact End-to-End Database Connection & Query Test

Tags: sql, database, oracle, integration-testing, end-to-end

The database is Oracle. The goal is to perform a **status check** in code that is:

- Robust
- End-to-end (healthy connection does NOT mean healthy objects, i.e. views with offline tables)
- Creates minimal overhead for calling application

To suffice these various requirements, I've come up with the following query:

```
SELECT NULL FROM VIEW_NAME WHERE NULL IS NOT NULL
```

So let's break it down:

- `SELECT NULL` is an attempt to "leverage" [SQL result caching](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-caching-pooling-088320.html) by explicitly specifying the value.
- `FROM VIEW_NAME` will fail if *VIEW_NAME* is not present in the database (i.e. end-to-end).
- `WHERE NULL IS NOT NULL` is an attempt to avert table scans, return 0 records, etc.

Any thoughts, improvements, suggestions, etc. would be appreciated. I would especially like to know if there are any conceivable issues with this query or approach.

Comment: You're gong to run this for every view and table, in case anything is offline or missing? What's the advantage of using this over `SELECT NULL FROM DUAL` for connectivity, and maybe looking at the data dictionary for offline/missing/invalid issues?

Comment: @AlexPoole To your point and to clarify, this is perhaps a check *specific* to an application's exclusive dependency on a single view. In this case, it wouldn't really matter if other views are offline, but to the application itself, it would matter a whole lot of this target view was unreachable. It's not really intended for conducting system-wide checks on every view/table, etc. Also, targeting a view (as in, `FROM VIEW_NAME`) is in fact end-to-end as `SELECT NULL FROM DUAL` would not test the accessibility of said view. I haven't looked into the data dictionary yet, however.

Answer (score 1):

You are better off checking for VALID objects under the user you are connecting as.

```
select count(*) from user_objects where status != 'VALID';
```

or if you are looking for all valid objects in DB, then:

```
select count(*) from obj$ where status != 'VALID';
```

Just make sure the query is not run too often - like 50 times a minute.

An even better approach would to be just be optimistic and attempt the operation - select/update/insert/delete that you want to do against the DB.

Invalid objects cause errors(which you will need to handle in your code anyway), so focus on having robust error handling in your application and don't worry about making a connection just to see if is all is OK in the DB.

Your test to check DB object status may pass, but the very next instant, the DB object can go invalid.

Comment: I might need to update the list of requirements to include this, but another side effect I would also be looking to mitigate are "fail-slow" queries where a minimum (or longer than desired) connection or query timeout may have previously been imposed. In this respect, I guess the question I'm posing would be more accurately described in the context of a "system monitor" of sorts. I do like the "check for valid objects" concept and will have to explore that more.